# How to set a different Rundeck user in a scheduled job?

Tags: rundeck

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a different Rundeck User to run a scheduled job? I created a user that can only perform 1 thing which is to run jobs. There is an existing job already that is scheduled to run every minute but I can't seem to find any options to change the user who will run the job. Thanks in advance to those who will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to change the scheduled job user is to save the same job as another user. But that sounds good for [enhancement](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).