# How do I modify existing jobs to switch owner?

Tags: rundeck

I installed Rundeck v3.3.5 (on CentOS 7 via RPM) to replace an old Rundeck instance that was decommissioned. I did the export/import of projects (which worked brilliantly) while connected to the new server as the default `admin` user. The imported jobs run properly on the correct schedule. I subsequently configured the new server to use LDAP authentication and configured ACLs for users/roles. That also works properly.

However, I see an error like this in the `service.log`:

> ERROR services.NotificationService - Error sending notification email to foo@bar.com for Execution 9358 Error executing tag <g:render>: could not initialize proxy [rundeck.Workflow#9468] - no Session

My thought is to switch job owners from `admin` to a user that exists in LDAP. I mean, I would like to switch job owners regardless, but I'm also hoping it addresses the error.

Is there a way in the web interface or using `rd` that I can bulk-modify jobs to switch the owner?

Comment: Could you share more info from the service.log file? Anyway, you can configure Rundeck to uses both login methods (local and LDAP) at the same time (Check this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#multiple-authentication-modules) and provide the right access read/execute jobs to your LDAP users via ACL (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/key-storage.html#acl-policies). It seems the same as https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/3156

Comment: Also, to change the user on scheduled jobs please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955975/10426011

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Thank you for the help! I didn't realize I could have multiple authentication configurations. I set that up, and I can now login as local admin or from LDAP. I tried saving the jobs as the desired owner, and that did change the user that appears as having run the job on schedule. However, it didn't change the `Error sending notification email to X` message in the log. The weird thing is that an email shouldn't have been generated, since it ran successfully. I'll keep an eye on this and see if I can determine the pattern.

Comment: Regarding `Error sending notification email to X` Can you try editing the job, saving it and check the scheduled job execution again on your new instance?

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I thought that might correct the problem too, but it doesn't have any effect. I grabbed the execution number of out the log, edited the job by viewing the activity list, saved it as the desired user. The activity log reflects that the next scheduled run was by the desired user, however I still get an error in the log. It doesn't seem to be related to who saved/scheduled the job.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I just figured it out by doing `rd jobs list -f /tmp/jobs.xml -p myproject` and searching through everything. Turns out, all the jobs that showed errors about context/session were included jobs by job reference in which I had a notification and hard-coded recipient. I didn't remember creating that. So, perhaps it's not possible to send a notification from an included job. I would bet the old instance also had errors in the log, but I wasn't looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error in the log was caused by notification settings in an included job. I didn't realize that notifications were configured on the parameterized shared job definition, but there were; removing the notification settings caused the error to stop being added to `/var/log/rundeck/service.log`.

To illustrate the problem, here are chunks of YAML I've edited to show just the important parts. Here's the common job:

```
- description: Do the actual work with arguments passed
  group: jobs/common
  id: a618ceb6-f966-49cf-96c5-03a0c2efb9d8
  name: do_the_work
  notification:
    onstart:
      email:
        attachType: file
        recipients: ops@company.com
        subject: Actual work being started
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  options:
  - enforced: true
    name: do_the_job
    required: true
    values:
    - yes
    - no
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  - enforced: true
    name: fail_a_lot
    required: true
    values:
    - yes
    - no
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  scheduleEnabled: false
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: The actual work
      script: |-
        #!/bin/bash
        echo ${RD_OPTION_DO_THE_JOB} ${RD_OPTION_FAIL_A_LOT}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  timeout: '60'
  uuid: a618ceb6-f966-49cf-96c5-03a0c2efb9d8
```

And here's the job that calls it (the one that is scheduled and causes an error to show up in the log when it runs):

```
- description: Do the job
  group: jobs/individual
  name: do_the_job
...
  notification:
    onfailure:
      email:
        recipients: ops@company.com
        subject: '[Rundeck] Failure of ${job.name}'
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
...
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: Call the job that does the work
      jobref:
        args: -do_the_job yes -fail_a_lot no
        group: jobs/common
        name: do_the_work
```

If I remove the notification settings from the common job, the error in the log goes away. I'm not sure if sending notifications from an included job is not supported. It would be useful to me if it was, so I could place notification settings in a single location. However, I can understand why it presents a problem for the scheduler/executor.