# Is there a way to edit a user/job in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to edit a user on a scheduled job in Rundeck? There are jobs scheduled and running but it needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

The only way right now is to edit the job with the desired user and save it again. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955975/10426011).